# How do I use OneDrive's picker in a web application with dynamic url and subdomains?

Tags: onedrive

I want to add the Onedrive file picker to my web application. But I have a problem related to the redirection url.

My website is a software as a service web application. We have hundreds of clients, each one in a subdomain. I want to add the file picker to multiple pages. Each page's url is going to be different because they are dynamic pages, they have an id on the url.

Like this:

client1.mydomain.com/page/1
client1.mydomain.com/page/2
client2.mydomain.com/page/3
client2.mydomain.com/page/4
client3.mydomain.com/page/5

So we have unlimited number of subdomains, each with an unlimited number of pages in which the url is all different.

Also, the number of pages that I can set in the App Registration portal is limited to 21. There are thousands of places where he picker should be available.

Solution? How can I use OneDrive's Picker in pages with dynamic url and multiple subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the authentication platform for OneDrive / OneDrive for Business. In order to use the file picker with tenant-specific URLs, you need to do some extra work.

Basically, you need to:

1. Have a single domain where you can host a single-page app (SPA) that provides the file picker interaction. Something like filepicker.myapp.com. On this page, you use the File Picker SDK and your app ID to authenticate, have the user pick a file, and redirect back to a page on filepicker.myapp.com. You can use the openInNewWindow=false property to ensure that the SPA app doesn't create a pop-up window.
2. From there, you can invoke your SPA from each of your tenant apps. Your tenant app creates a new pop-up window, invokes the SPA app, and uses postMessage() or query strings to communicate between your tenant app and your SPA. This is the hand off from the tenant app to the file picker SPA, and the method through which your SPA will send the results of the picked file back to your tenant app.

This is definitely a pain-point, and we're investigating ways we can make the authentication platform more robust for applications that have tenant-based URLs but don't have any firm commitments on when we'll have something better available.